# How to declare desired type to avoid ".. Ambigious reference.."

Tags: c#, class, reference, namespaces, alias

i.e. I have bunch of methods in project:

```
private void a(Brush x) ...
private void b(Brush x) ...
private void c(Brush x) ...
```

it says "Brush is ambigious reference between `System.Windows.Media.Brush` and `System.Drawing.Brush`.

How can i globally (in the head of file) declare that `Brush` should be dealed as one of those types in all occasions?

Comment: by using something like `using B = TheActualNamespace.Brush`. and then refering that type using `B b = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Brush = System.Windows.Media.Brush;
```

Comment: This answer is partial, if the aliased namespace is not referenced in the code the ambigous reference would remain. My personal preference would be using a alias in both namespaces to avoid confusion in the code.